# Error: Cannot initialize return object of type "int *" with an lvalue of type 'int [r][c]'

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, pointers

I am trying to build some .cpp code, in an XCode project. I have a very simple function that converts a matrix of data type cv::Mat (from opencv), to a simple two-dimensional c++ array.

The function looks something like this:

```
int* myClass::convertMatrix(cv::Mat cvmat){
    int r = cvmat.rows;
    int c = cvmat.cols;
    int newmat[r][c];
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
            newmat[i][j] = cvmat.at<int>(i, j);
        }
    }
    return newmat;
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I know "lvalue" refers to a specific memory location, but what does this have to do with me returning a matrix?

Comment: why don't you just use `std::vector`?

Comment: I am passing the data to be handled by swift on the front-end, so I would like to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: In that case, just make `newmat` as 1-D array. But what's more important is that `newmat` will be destroyed when the function ends.

Comment: I need to dynamically allocate memory then?

Comment: If you really want to return a array from the function, yes. But you must free it after use.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to return a pointer to a temporary variable inside that function.
After the function is being returned, that variable is automatically being cleaned up by the compiler.

Also, you are trying to create a stack-allocated array with parameters that are unknown at compile-time, if you had the size of the array at compile-time, you could have marked `r` and `c` as `constexpr`, if it didn't complain about that consider reading about [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

To fix those issues, just allocate the array on the heap:

```cpp
int** make_2d_array(int r, int c) 
{
    int** arr = new int*[r];
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        arr[i] = new int[c];

    return arr;
}

int** myClass::convertMatrix(cv::Mat cvmat){
    int r = cvmat.rows;
    int c = cvmat.cols;
    int** newmat = make_2d_array(r, c);

    for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
            newmat[i][j] = cvmat.at<int>(i, j);
        }
    }

    return newmat;
}
```

**Don't forget to delete the array when you stopped using it.**

I also recommend considering using `std::vector` for that, so you don't have to worry about deleting the array ( way simpler ):

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> newmat(r, std::vector<int>(c));
```